# Proving function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ using total derivative definition

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I am looking at the function: $$\frac{x\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$ at $(0,0)$, where the function at $(0,0)$ is defined to be $0$.

I understand that I need to check that: $$\lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{{f(\mathbf{a} + \mathbf{h}) - f(\mathbf{a}) - A\mathbf{h}}}{{\|\mathbf{h}\|}} = \lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{{f(\mathbf{h})}}{{\|\mathbf{h}\|}} = 0 \ .$$

Since $D_1f$ and $D_2f$ are equal to zero, I believe that A is the matrix $(0, 0)$. I've tried going through different paths to see if I get a different limit when doing: $$\lim_{{h \to 0}} \frac{{f(\mathbf{h})}}{{\|\mathbf{h}\|}} \ ,$$ and all of them give me $0$.

Therefore, I believe that function is differentiable at $(0,0)$. But how can I prove it more soundly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can use that $\|h\|_2 = \sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}$ for $h\in\mathbb{R}^2$. If we now have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ with $f(0)=0$ and we want to prove that $f'(0)=0$, this means that we have to show
\begin{equation}\tag{1}0=\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{|f(0+h)-f(0)-f'(0)h|}{\|h\|_2} =\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{|f(h)|}{\|h\|_2}. \end{equation}

Now, in your case, $f(x,y)=\frac{x\sin(xy)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $, i.e.
$$\frac{|f(h)|}{\|h\|_2} = \frac{|h_1\sin(h_1h_2)|}{h_1^2+h_2^2}  $$
Using that $|\sin(t)|\leq |t|$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we can estimate it further:

$$\frac{|h_1\sin(h_1h_2)|}{h_1^2+h_2^2} \leq \frac{h_1^2|h_2|}{h_1^2+h_2^2} = \frac{|h_2|}{1+\left(\frac{h_2}{h_1}\right)^2}\leq \frac{|h_2|}{1+0} = |h_2|\leq \sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}=\|h\|_2 $$
So if $\|h\|_2\longrightarrow 0$, this inequality tells us that also $\lim\limits_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{|f(h)|}{\|h\|_2}=0$ which by $(1)$ means that $f$ is totally differentiable at $0$ with derivative $f'(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using polar coordinates. The limit $h\to 0$ is equivalent to $r\to 0$. Then let $A=(a\ b)$, $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$.
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\cos\theta\sin(r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)-a\cos\theta-b\sin\theta}{r}=0$$
For the first part, use $$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\sin(r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta)}{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}=1$$
If you want your limit to be $0$, independent of $\theta$, then $a=b=0$. And you got your intuitive solution.